# Android Studio Java (generated) files are posing errors while running the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just imported a project in my Android Studio. When I tried to refactor the package name, I started facing errors. I am a beginner in Android so just need your help.
When I refactored the package name by renaming the first folder after java. It did change the folder name but there were some imports in files of java (generated). Now I am unable to optimize imports in the generated files as it cannot be changed and all the changes are lost.

[image: ERRORS screenshot]

Comment: you are trying to change the packagename of auto generated java folder, which u dont need to

Comment: I didn't change the package name of the generated java folder. It got changed automatically when I changed the name of the main java folder.

Comment: just close the folder and sync files with gradle

Comment: I tried it. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are under java (generated) folder ...

those java files should not be edited...

those are generated by compiler....

it is clearly written above it should not be edited

as you said `I am trying to refactor the package name` just refer this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/12553303)

Thanks

Comment: @BasitBee you are under java (generated) folder ...those java files should not be edited...those are generated by compiler....it is clearly written above it should not be edited

Comment: Then how can I optimize the imports? As I am trying to refactor the package name.

Comment: refer this for refactoring --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/12553303

Comment: Thanks @Wini, your reference helped. The issue is solved by doing "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project" after refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

from `Android Studio IDE` file menu -> Invalidate Cache and restart -> Invalidate Cache and restart.

this should solve your errors

Comment: I tried doing "Invalidate Cache and Restart" but I did not solve the errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to change the name of the package try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1). what is the purpose to edit a generated file